# Cannot successfully install sonar 2.14

Tags: sonarqube

My machine uses 32 bit windows xp as the operating system and I just want to use Apache Derby for testing sonar.Any help will be appreciated. Here is the log file

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2012-04-11 08:39:52.774:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
jvm 1    | 2012-04-11 08:39:52.805:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
jvm 1    | 2012-04-11 08:39:52.915:INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
jvm 1    | JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
jvm 1    | gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
jvm 1    | Server must be upgraded. Please browse /setup
jvm 1    | 2012-04-11 08:40:03.763:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:9000
```

Comment: Is that means I need to put a jar file including this org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following message "Server must be upgraded", this means that you have installed Sonar 2.14 on a previous version (or you have copied the Derby folder to the new install). We explicitly specify on our documentation that migration is not supported for Derby: this means that you should install Sonar 2.14 on a fresh location (or remove the old install folder).